# Unable to retrieve data in window phone app using button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, asynchronous

Hi just started on Window Phone app and i'm not sure how to retrieve data to link to textblock
I am using a pivot app and i need to save it to 3 textboxes and display it in "ALL"

MainPage.xaml

```
  <phone:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">

  <phone:PivotItem Header="All" Margin="10,0,14,32">



  <Canvas>

  <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Admin : " Canvas.Left="57" Canvas.Top="125"/>
  <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Canvas.Left="57" Canvas.Top="201" Width="73">
  <Run Text="Name:"/>
  <LineBreak/>
                        <Run/>
                </TextBlock>
                <Button Content="Retrieve " Canvas.Left="165" Canvas.Top="484" Click="Btn_Retrieve"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="Valuespace" TextWrapping="Wrap" Canvas.Left="152" Canvas.Top="125" Height="110" Width="170"/>
            </Canvas>


        </phone:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="Admin">
            <!--Double line list no text wrapping-->
            <Canvas>
                <TextBox Name="TbAdmin" Height="69" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="296" Canvas.Top="151" Canvas.Left="78"/>
                <Button Content="Save" Canvas.Left="152" Canvas.Top="344" Height="76" Width="143" Click="btn_Save"/>

            </Canvas>
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <phone:PivotItem Header="Name" Margin="14,0,10,28">
            <!--Double line list no text wrapping-->
            <Canvas>
                <TextBox Name="TbName" Height="69" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="296" Canvas.Top="151" Canvas.Left="78"/>
                <Button Content="Save" Height="76" Width="159" Canvas.Left="143" Canvas.Top="290" Click="btn_Save"/>

            </Canvas>
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <phone:PivotItem Header="Update">
            <!--Double line list no text wrapping-->
            <Canvas>
                <TextBox Name="TbUpdate" Height="69" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="296" Canvas.Top="151" Canvas.Left="78"/>
                <Button Content="Save" Canvas.Left="161" Canvas.Top="325" Height="91" Width="140" Click="btn_Save"/>

            </Canvas>
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>


</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using MockTest.Resources;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;

namespace MockTest
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    // Load data for the ViewModel Items
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
    }

    async void btn_Save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("Store.txt",       
    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(TbAdmin.Text);
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(TbName.Text);
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(TbUpdate.Text);
            await writer.FlushAsync();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }

    async void Btn_Retrieve(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        using (var Stream = await folder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("Store.txt")) 
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(Stream);
            var result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            MessageBox.Show(result);
        }

    }
```

I am able to show the details in the MessageBox but i want it to display in a textblock matching with admin and Name but not showing update. Is there anyway to do it as i dont really know what to write in async.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to retrieve the data, you may have something that looks like this with your current code.

*"Admin\r\nName\r\nUpdate\r\n"*

As you are saving the data in three lines, which are stored line by line. You could do something like divide the single long string back into individual lines.

```
var splitBy = new[] { "\r\n" };
var splitResult = result.Split(splitBy, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Then, as you have entered the data in groups of three lines, one for each of your textbox's. You can simply loop through the *splitResults* and grab three items at a time.

You can then use something along the lines off...

```
TextBlock.Text = string1;
```

I would keep the focus on the async to a minimum at the moment and first get your data into your **TextBlock**.

I also see you are adding a linebreak and using run in your textblock. Maybe come away from that for now and add another textblock that will hold the returned admin & name. As that will lead you down the use of **inlines** and is another learning curve for you.

So under the **TextBlock** which you have something like this...

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Admin : " Canvas.Left="57" Canvas.Top="125"/>
```

Put another textblock underneath it and name it what you would like. Then in the code behind you can access that **TextBlock** via it's name and set it's text directly.

I'm also removing empty entries from the string split, which you will need to think on if you ever enter empty strings etc.